# [C/C++]WebKitGtk get scrollbar position

Tags: c++, c, webkit, webkitgtk, webkit2

I'm trying to get the scrollbar position in a WebKitWebView.
I've read enough documentation to know that there's no intuitive way.

It needs to be packaged into one executable, so a WebKitExtension won't cut it out.

I don't even know where to begin so I won't be writing any MRE

Note: I could use JavaScript if the need arises, but I don't know how to communicate with the native application in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: this source code is pretty bad. Use it if and only if you're gonna correct it.

Ok y'all little boys, girls and non-euclidean space beings, I've come to infatuate your sad, tired and frustrated neurons with some delicious knowledge:

I've done it (AT LONG LAST), 3 weeks after asking this question. I've had to use a WebKitExtension in order to do this. Rejoice your brain and cerebellum, for an example shitty source code is here:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h>
#include <JavaScriptCore/JavaScript.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <filesystem>

#define SLEEP_PERIOD 5

static void save_pos(WebKitWebPage * web_page)
{
  std::ofstream tmp_file;
  tmp_file.open((std::string) std::filesystem::current_path() + "/poslck");
  tmp_file << "e";
  tmp_file.close();
  sleep(SLEEP_PERIOD + 1);
  std::filesystem::remove((std::string) std::filesystem::current_path() + "/poslck");
  WebKitDOMDocument * doc = webkit_web_page_get_dom_document(web_page);
  WebKitDOMDOMWindow * win = webkit_dom_document_get_default_view(doc);

  std::ofstream o; 

  while(true && !std::filesystem::exists((std::string) std::filesystem::current_path() + "/poslck"))
  {
    sleep(SLEEP_PERIOD);
    o.open(std::filesystem::current_path().string() + "/pos.conf");
    o <<  webkit_dom_dom_window_get_scroll_y(win);
    o.close();

  }
  
}

static void 
window_object_cleared_callback (WebKitScriptWorld *world, 
                                WebKitWebPage *web_page, 
                                WebKitFrame *frame, 
                                gpointer user_data)
{ 


  
  std::thread dothesaving(std::bind(save_pos, web_page));
  dothesaving.detach();
  
}

extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void
webkit_web_extension_initialize (WebKitWebExtension *extension)
{
    std::cout << "[INFO] Extension initialized\n";
    
    g_signal_connect (webkit_script_world_get_default(),
                      "window-object-cleared", 
                      G_CALLBACK (window_object_cleared_callback), 
                      NULL);


    
}
```

Compile it with: `` g++ extension.cpp -shared -fPIC -o extension.so `pkg-config webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 --libs --cflags` -std=c++17 ``

Also: please take a look at the official documentation for more guidelines to know how the hecc you could use extensions in your WebKitGTK project.

Before anybody begins hating me: I've used deprecated functions for this to work and I've used temporary files. The reason is that I don't know how to use the JavaScriptCore API (I'm still to see where is the documentation) and also that I don't know how to communicate between extensions.